# Sum dataframe by conditionally defined groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, rows

I have python dataframe, I want to sum across different rows, separated by number 0. E.g: i have this DF here:

```
data= DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],'B':[1,2,0,3,2,0,0,3,4]})
```

I want to generate this DF:

```
data2= DataFrame({'AA':'a','d','h'],'BB':[3,5,7]})
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Only I can do is using a loop to sum, when meets an 0 stops and loop next section. There should be an easier way in DataFrame.

Comment: Is it important to keep the 'AA' column as 'a', 'd', 'h'?

Comment: @xg.plt.py yeah it's important, in the real situation, AA column records the date.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to define some groups using the function cumsum:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],'B':[1,2,0,3,2,0,0,3,4]})
data['groups'] = (data['B'] == 0).cumsum() 
# Out 
#    A  B  groups
# 0  a  1       0
# 1  b  2       0
# 2  c  0       1
# 3  d  3       1
# 4  e  2       1
# 5  f  0       2
# 6  g  0       3
# 7  h  3       3
# 8  i  4       3
```

Then, define an array with the output indices, which except for the first are one below the first occurrence of each group:

```
indexes = data.loc[data.drop_duplicates('groups').index.values+1]['A'].values
indexes[0] = data['A'].values[0]
```

And eventually, grouping by, summing column a for each group and assigning the new AA column.

```
sum_data = data.groupby('groups').sum().assign(AA=indexes).reset_index(drop=True)
# Out
#    B AA
# 0  3  a
# 1  5  d
# 2  0  g
# 3  7  h
```

if having the row [2, 0, g] present is a nuisance, this last line can be added:

```
sum_data = sum_data[sum_data['B'] != 0]
# Out
#    B AA
# 0  3  a
# 1  5  d
# 3  7  h
```

Comment: Perfect solution, Cumsum function is great .. thanks buddy!